# While loop stop condition missing

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, heap

In this [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/min-heap-in-java/) **min heap** implementation, it looks like `insert` method `while` loop boundary condition is missing a check.

Correct me if I am wrong?

```
public void insert(int element) {
    if (size >= maxsize) {
        return;
    }
    Heap[++size] = element;
    int current = size;

    while (Heap[current] < Heap[parent(current)]) {
        swap(current, parent(current));
        current = parent(current);
    }
}


private void swap(int fpos, int spos) {
    int tmp;
    tmp = Heap[fpos];
    Heap[fpos] = Heap[spos];
    Heap[spos] = tmp;
}

private int parent(int pos) {
    return pos / 2;
}
```

Q1. Should not `while` loop be:

```
while (current != 0 && Heap[current] < Heap[parent(current)])
```

instead of

```
while (Heap[current] < Heap[parent(current)])
```

Q2. Formula to calculate parent be

```
private int parent(int pos) {
        return (pos - 1) / 2;
    }
```

Q3. And formula to calculate left and right children
instead of:

```
    private int leftChild(int pos) 
    { 
        return (2 * pos); 
    } 

    private int rightChild(int pos) 
    { 
        return (2 * pos) + 1; 
    }
```

Should be

```
    private int leftChild(int pos) 
    { 
        return (2 * pos) + 1; 
    } 

    private int rightChild(int pos) 
    { 
        return (2 * pos) + 2; 
    }
```

Comment: Actually that article has an odd mixture of a 0-indexed and 1-indexed heap, I'm not sure what they intended with that.. neither is wrong but mixing them sure is odd.

Comment: If it is **one indexed** `array` then will while loop end condition be valid, as index at 1 will return parent as 0 = (int) 1/2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parent` of 0 is also 0, you could argue that it's not really its own parent, but that's how the formula works out.

The root of the heap cannot be less than itself, so the loop stops there automatically.

There are, roughly, two versions of the parent and left/right child formulas: one version that works with a 1-indexed array (the root has index 1) and one version that works with a 0-indexed array (root has index 0). In the 0-indexed version, the child-indexes are formed by appending a 0 or 1 bit to the parent index (on the least-significant side), and the parent index is found from a child index by dropping the least significant bit. The 1-indexed version has to compensate with an extra offset.

Comment: well then, if head is at index- 1, parent of index-1 ( parent = (int) 1/2;) will be zero and if it is **One Indexed** array, not sure what to keep at index - 0. Will index zero be Integer.MAX_VALUE to terminate while loop?

Comment: @SwarupRanjanSahoo `Integer.MIN_VALUE` I think

Comment: Yes, Integer.MIN_VALUE for min heap assuming it is an Integer min-heap